# Where to find default widget style values

Tags: android

I need to find some default style values. In my case that is the default padding values of edittext. I found something in `android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-xx\data\res\values\styles.xml`, however there are no information about `edittext` padding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EditText`s use a 9-patch image as background, so the padding is actually defined in the .9.png file referenced from `styles.xml` as `background`.

Comment: Ok, that is what I do aswell, however I create my ninepatch programmatically from a bitmap resource (that is actually a ninepatch) and get its chunk data via getNinePatchChunk. This works for Imagebuttons but not properly for edittexts, where left and right padding stay 0. I created the black horizontal line on the buttom that is responsible for left and right padding. Well I guess the question how I asked it is answered, thank you.

Comment: @SnoK: Try to validate your 9-patch, compare it to the native one android uses for the `EditText`. Perhaps even post a link to your 9-patch, if you think there could be anything wrong with it.

Comment: Have you tried the 9patch editor that comes with the SDK? draw9patch? Also see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch and http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html and http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html